# Add padding to text but not images

Tags: html, css, alignment, padding

Im trying to make a Tumblr theme, and trying to make text go away from the border 20px, but it is also pushing the photos, videos, and other elements that are not text over, which is IS supposed to do, is there a way to only align the text?

```
        .posts {
            border:solid 1px #333333;
            border-radius:15px 15px 15px 15px;
            color:black;
            margin-bottom:20px;
            min-height:120px;
            padding-left:20px;
            text-align:left;
        }
```

Thats my code.

http://puu.sh/83iTL.jpg

Thats what is happening, but I want to only align the text.  Is this possible?

Thanks :)

EDIT: The entire code: http://pastebin.com/6q4hFyZL and the page is em202020.tumblr.com

Comment: You should wrap your text in its own class, and then only apply the padding to that class.

Comment: What if you add negative left margin(-20px) to the elements like photos and videos that you don't want to go away from the border?

Comment: make a class for ur text and apply padding to that class like Alex said

Comment: if thats the final option I have, then I will, its going to take a while though, because I would need to add it to every type of post that tumblr has :s
Thanks :)

Comment: Give us the link to your page, so we see the html generated and can advise you clearly. Your HTML is missing, we cannot guess it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<edit>
```

From your page : http://em202020.tumblr.com/

You could do:

```
.posts   a:first-of-type img,
.posts iframe {
margin-left:-80px;
}
```

Or if you like it better :

```
.posts   a:first-of-type img {
    margin-left:-80px;
    }
 .posts iframe {
margin-left:-20px;
    }
```

.`</edit>`

---

*first guess answer irrelevant.
you can do :*

```
.posts img:first-child {/* it will only select the first-child if it is an img tag */
margin-left:-20px;/* swallow that padding-left:20px; */
}
```

Comment: Tumblr is kind of weird when it comes to adding content, but this is my entire code:
http://pastebin.com/6q4hFyZL

Comment: for the code , i meant the generated HTML than you see can through your browser (show source) , so we get the  structure and attributes used and to style :)

Comment: @em202020 , best , do you have the link to your page ?

Answer (score 0):

could you add css rules for .post img?

```
        .posts {
        border:solid 1px #333333;
        border-radius:15px 15px 15px 15px;
        color:black;
        margin-bottom:20px;
        min-height:120px;
        padding-left:20px;
        text-align:left;
    }


       #add this?#
       .posts img {
       padding:0px;
```

Comment: it won'nt 'kill' padding on .posts

Comment: can you post the html too?